# Cordova app using WebSQL hit quota limit and cannot recover

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, web-sql

I have hit a quota roadblock on iOS using standard Cordova WebSQL (with MS OpenTech polyfill plugin but I don't think it actually uses that on iOS).

An error is thrown from WebSQL indicating quota exceeded. When this happens I catch the error and drop my main table, then refresh it from the internet.

However, when it hits the quota limit it either will not allow a `drop table` statement to proceed or the drop statement doesn't free any space because the quota error still keeps coming up. Does anyone know why dropping the table wouldn't free space? I have also tried the `vacuum` statement which thinks for a while but does not appear to free any space either.

Note that this is an existing app in the field so I would prefer not to switch out the database platform unless we need to. (I see there is a plugin available now (https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext) which says it has no quota limit - could be the best/only solution?)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to replace my default WebSQL with the plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

It went extremely well. This plugin swapped out without any code changes needed in my SQL statements!!! Very pleased!

I tested adding a couple of GB of data to the database and it performed very well and at no point stopped accepting data.

By the way, I tested the limits default WebSQL on iOS and found it dies in a screaming heap at 50MB exactly. You cannot delete any data, drop or vacuum from that point and so you can never recover. It is a pretty serious bug! (This is still recommended as an option on the Cordova docs - it should come with a serious warning)